# How to correctly use the palatino font (in memoir)?

Tags: fonts, memoir, fontsize, mathpazo

I'm preparing a PhD thesis (using memoir and pdfLaTeX), and I find the palatino font a nice body font.

Reading the font related questions and answers on this awesome site, I think I have pieced together the correct combination of commands and packages but it feels like a lot of hacking.
So I want to ask if there is a better way than my current solution.

I've added comments in the below example.

```
\RequirePackage[sc]{mathpazo} % use mathpazo to get the math fonts working correctly, why can't we scale them?
\RequirePackage[scale=0.95]{tgpagella}\normalfont % but use tgpagella as main font (it's newer than mathpazo?}
\newcommand*{\memfontfamily}{qpl} % tgpagella as main memoir font
\newcommand*{\memfontenc}{T1}
\newcommand*{\memfontpack}{tgpagella}
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt, extrafontsizes, showtrims, draft]{memoir}
\RequirePackage[scaled=0.75]{luximono}  % we can load the correct tt font after the document class
% tgpagella contains no slanted shapes, so lets borrow them from mathpazo 
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{sl} { <-> ssub * pplj/m/sl }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{sl} { <-> ssub * pplj/b/sl }{}

%just some stuff for the demo page
\setlrmarginsandblock  {30mm}{*}{*}
\setlxvchars \setxlvchars[\small\sffamily]
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout


\usepackage[final, babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath which also loads fonts?

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Regular font families}

\textrm{roman text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4] }

\textit{italic text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4]}

\textbf{boldface text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4] }

\textsl{slanted text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4] }

\texttt{typewriter text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4] }

\chapter{Lesser used types}
\textit{\textbf{italic bold  text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4]}}

\textsl{\textbf{slanted bold  text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4]}}

\textsc{smallcaps: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4] }

\textsc{\textbf{smallcaps bold  text: (ffi --- --) \\ \lipsum[4]}}

\chapter{Other test cases}

\textrm{Regular text (\texttt{http://tttext}) and \textbf{bold text} and \textit{italic text} and \textsl{slanted text}}


 \textrm{\LARGE Regular text (\texttt{http://tttext}) and \textbf{bold text} and \textit{italic text} and \textsl{slanted text}}

\textrm{ }
\textrm{ffi --- }

\begin{equation}
d=Xh+S\phi+\varepsilon \label{eq:fMRIAnalysisChapter3}
\end{equation}                  


\begin{equation}
h=\left( X^TP_sX\right)^{-1} X^T P_s d  \label{eq:Eq2Chapter3}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So I want to use the newest `tgpagella` font, but it does not offer a math font, so we first load `mathpazo` to later only overwrite the body font with the `tgpagella` fonts. But we have to use `luximono` as a nice companion typewriter font. Then to solve all the warnings we borrow the slanted shapes from the `mathpazo` font.

At the moment, I think it looks fairly good, although I'm not entirely happy about the spacing/sizes in the math example and the fact that the `mathpazo` shapes are slightly larger then `tgpagella`.

So the question, is this really the best way? And what would you do to improve this?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to use Pagella and Pazo at the same time? When it comes to fonts "newer" does not always translate to "better".

Comment: well, Pagella does nothing for the math of a document. and I like Pagella a bit more since it allows me to slightly scale it down.

Comment: Your "slanted roman" font does not seem to be set up correctly: When I run your code, on p. 3 of the output file I definitely get italics and not slanted-roman. Separately: If you're going to use `pdflatex`, you might as well stick with the `mathpazo` package for both text and math, unless you need lots of accented characters (for which `tgpagella` will be useful). If you wish to use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`, you could use the `Asana Math` package and together with Hermann Zapf's fully-updated (2005) `Palatino nova` text font (from Linotype, in otf format); not free, though.

Comment: @Mico I agree, that was wrong, it just looked differenlty, but that was off course because mathpazo also doesn't define a slanted roman font. Could you clarify why you feel tgpagella provides no advantage?

Comment: Davy, I'm sorry if I implied that the `tgpagella` font package provides *no* advantages (relative to `mathpazo`). If you have lots of words with accented characters, you're certainly better off loading `tgpagella` as the (text) font. Conversely, if you have no need to typeset accented characters, I don't see what advantages that the non-opentype version of `tgpagella` may have for you -- better to keep your setup as simple as possible. Moreover, I like the "small caps" font shape of mathpazo more than tgpagella's version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pplj` family has no slanted font: indeed the relevant line in `t1pplj.fd` reads

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplj}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * pplj/m/it}{}
```

If you want to avoid the messages, you can write

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{sl} { <-> ssub * qpl/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{sl} { <-> ssub * qpl/b/it }{}
```

so getting Pagella Italic. The most convenient way is just not using slanted, because it doesn't exist.

If I remove the `scale=0.95` option from the call to `tgpagella`, I get characters that are the same width as the normal Palatino provided by `mathpazo`. If you want smaller fonts, just use 9pt as the main size.

I see bad spacing in the second math formula only because you say `\left(...\right)`, which in this case is wrong.

There is no need to do `\RequirePackage` before `\documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 9pt, extrafontsizes, showtrims, draft]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % choose the default encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel} % choose the language

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % use mathpazo for math fonts
\usepackage{tgpagella} % but use tgpagella as main font
\usepackage[scaled=0.75]{luximono}

% Are the following really necessary? I don't think so
%\renewcommand*{\memfontfamily}{qpl} % tgpagella as main memoir font
%\renewcommand*{\memfontenc}{T1}
%\renewcommand*{\memfontpack}{tgpagella}

\normalfont % we want to avoid annoying warnings
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{sl} { <-> ssub * qpl/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{sl} { <-> ssub * qpl/b/it }{}

\linespread{1.05} % add something to the interline skip
\setlrmarginsandblock  {30mm}{*}{*}
\setlxvchars \setxlvchars[\small\sffamily]
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout


\usepackage[final, babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath which also loads fonts?

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}
```

Comment: hi egreg, thank you for your answer, I thought I read in the memoir manual (p15) that for extrafontsizes and other calculations to work you would have to load the fonts before the \documentclass. Why is using `\left(...\right)` wrong here? I thought you always had to do that?

Comment: I get the same results with or without `mathpazo`; `extrafontsizes` is needed only if you need to pass an option such as 25pt; it is evident that `\left` and `\right` choose too large a parenthesis, in that case.