# How do I set Palatino as a font in Memoir?

Tags: fonts, memoir

*First of all, I don't think this is a duplicate of [How to correctly use the palatino font (in memoir)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43881/18648), because it appears to be a very specific use case.*

In `memoir`, I'd like to use the Palatino font family. It's documented as

> The fontfamily name is `ppl`.

And setting the fontfamily in `memoir` appears to be very complicated. In section 1.2.1 of the `memman.pdf` it is shown like this:

```
\newcommand*{\memfontfamily}{<fontfamily>}
```

So I provide it like this:

```
\newcommand*{\memfontfamily}{ppl}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{memoir}
```

But it doesn't work and the default font family is still produced in the pdf.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's as easy as `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}`

Comment: Please read that section again, `\memfontfamily` is only used when you are using extended font sizes. @egregs solution will work in any cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default  (old) Palatino package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}

foo \textbf{bar} \textsf{baz} $y=\sqrt{x}$

\end{document}
```

Or with the new TeX Gyre Pagella (the better choice), which uses by default TeX Gyre Heros for the sans serif text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}

foo \textbf{bar} \textsf{baz} $y=\sqrt{x}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second option is a bit confusing: The sentence leading up to it mentions TeX Gyre Pagella, but the example code mentions the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages, which both derive from the `pxfonts` package -- which has been around a lot longer than TeX Gyre Pagella. Please clarify.

Comment: What do you want to clarify? The `pxfont` package defines the family `pxr` as `\rmdefault` and `newpxtext` the family `zplx` which itself refers to TeX Gyre (see file `t1zplx.fd`)

Comment: I would have thought that the most obvious (LaTeX) method for loading the TeX Gyre Pagella fonts would have been to issue the command `\usepackage{tgpagella}`. That package contains the instruction `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qpl}`, so its fonts are not (or not necessarily) the same as those used by the `pxfonts`, `newpxtext`, and `newpxmath` packages.